# Unable to put all of my data (<2Kb) into the data field in my firebase notification

Tags: firebase, firebase-notifications

I have to make a service in my app to send daily messages. These messages are usually between 2-3 Kb (1 paragraph or more precisely 250 to 375 characters long) long.

The firebase docs say that we can send upto 4kb of data using its notification service. So I tried putting this message into the field with the appropriate tag in the "Advanced Options" section. 
But I can't fit even 200 characters of data (200*8 = 1600 < 2Kb) in the data field.

What I can seem to do is to split the message int sections and use different fields. But that's not good because then Each day I'll have to first split the message and then enter it accordingly.

[Screenshot of trying to fit in one field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YtFB.png)

The main message text is "New message" and the data name is aa

That makes 201 + 11  + 2 = 224 chars. that's less than 2 kb, and firebase docs are saying upto 4kb data can be sent.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better approach. A classic approach to using FCM for tasks like this is to have the message just trigger a fetch. When the message is received in the app, you make a separate request to your server to retrieve the data. In this way, you aren't affected by the message limits (or the limits imposed by the console).